# Possible to get low level information from referrer in PHP

Tags: php, apache, curl, reverse-proxy, referer

Is it possible for PHP to determine the following scenario:

**Server "A"** : I do not own or have control over the server. I am able to post web links on this server to my server.

**Server "B"** : My own server running PHP and Apache.

: I want to post a link on server "A" and when I click the link and hit server "B", I want to retrieve all the information about the originating link as possible. Including Ajax calls made to get to my server. HTTP_REFERER is not giving me the info I need.

When I run Charles or Fiddler in the app UI, I see the GET requests I need. But I'm not sure PHP is able to "reverse engineer" this request automatically in the scenario I outlined.

some things that come to mind (which could be off base)

CURL referrer 
Reverse proxy
Charles/Fiddler2

Comment: Not sure you understand how links or referrers work. If you post a link on an external site, and someone clicks on that, there are no ajax calls. In fact there are no more calls to server A at all. The browser itself just fills in the referrer and then loads server B. Unless, of course, there are details about Server A you're not telling (does it mess with your link somehow? Does your link contain some javascript code?)

Comment: yes it does mess with my link, in a fairly major way. All i'm getting through PHP currently is the main domain URL.

Comment: You need to detail these link changes so that we can help. Currently I have nothing intelligent to offer.

Comment: Ok, NP. I'm trying to post a link to Twitter and I want to know what post the link came from regardless of the client used or how it was accessed on the website.

Comment: That's not possible. You should've said that in the first place. Your link appearing in hundreds of different software clients is not the same as "my link on some site A".

Comment: I believe I am having the same issue as you. Maybe others can look at my question and live example page to get a better idea of the issue? Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946744/getting-the-domain-that-calls-an-php-file-on-your-server-through-ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking a link on external site A to your site B results in a single HTTP request to your server, with site A's URL as the referrer header. There is no other information.

Answer (score 0):

Mmm Just my 2 cents:

You could post a link with injected javascript in server A, that could make an ajax call to the same server to get HTTP headers like "Server" and "X-Powered-By", then submit them to server A with a cross-domain post. They're only headers, but I hope it helps you at least a little.

Comment: Edgar, I didn't mark you down but I marked you back up again. This solution won't work in my situation as I'm unable to put javascript into twitter messages obviously but you were not aware that this was for Twitter when you answered and it would have been helpful otherwise. :) - thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Have you thought about using session variables to help you out with this?  There is an option in php which allows you to pass the session id as part of the url (instead of a cookie).

Look for "session.use_trans_sid" on this page:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: Session variables only contain information that you put in them in the first place. They won't have information about where someone found a link to your site in them.