# Getting the domain that calls an PHP file on your server through AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, api, referer

I'm building out an API and have a question about how to track/know which domains use the call.

The API call is built in PHP, and doesn't require any authentication.  A user will most likely use the API in an AJAX call on their server.

So for example, my domain that is serving up the API PHP file is called dev.yourmapper.com.  Someone on the domain www.metromapper.org builds a page that creates a Google map, and calls my file using Ajax to overlay my data on their map.

Here is that example in action: http://www.metromapper.org/example/apitest.htm

(Click the center map marker to see a popup of all the PHP Server variables available to the yourmapper.com script.)

Note that HTTP_REFERER is likely going to be 'stackoverflow.com' if you click the link (or empty if you cut and paste the link).  I would think that the referer would be metromapper.org, since that domain calls the yourmapper.com script after it loads, but apparently not.

Bottom line: what method can I use to determine which domain is calling my yourmapper.com script with Javascript?  I can use other languages besides PHP if needed.  Thanks.

Comment: From a comment just left by someone, they suggested using REMOTE_HOST and REMOTE_ADDR, which you can see in the marker popup.  Turns out this is Google's IP address, which is where my yourmapper.com data goes before being served up by Google.  http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/74.125.75.3  So it might not be possible to get the IP/Domain of the originating page....

Comment: It's not clear from the above whether your API is called from a server or the webpage where the map sits (e.g. through JSONP, bypassing the server that served the page.) If the latter, you can probably append the URL of the page where the Javascript sits -- `window.location` -- to your ajax call.

Comment: @chris-carson My API at dev.yourmapper.com can be called from any person's web page (like metromapper.org).  The API can serve data as JSON, but in this case it is being served as KML to overlay directly on the map.  Since I don't have control over another person's Javascript code, I can't force them to add `window.location` to the KML request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"I would think that the referer would be metromapper.org, since that domain calls the yourmapper.com script after it loads"

That's incorrect actually. Firstly you should never rely on the HTTP_REFERER because it's a voluntary parameter passed by most (not all) browsers, and it can easily be spoofed. I can send your website requests using CURL that make it look like the referrer was whitehouse.gov if I want to. There's no security measures in place there.

That being said. The browser sets that parameter to the page that referred the user to the currently loaded page. Not script. So the reason you see the result you're seeing is because the user was referred to metromapper.org by a link on stackoverflow.com

Finally, let's get to the juicy part. You're using JS to code things in the browser. That's fine and there's absolutely no problem with that. But you have to remember that JS is open source. So people can (and will) mess with your code to play with your API just because they can. That being said. Your best bet is probably to pass the url of the site along with the request in your JS api. That's the best way to "track" what sites are using your script. You could check server side to make sure that a URL was passed. That would prevent people from modifying your API to remove the bit that sends their URL to your server. It won't, however, prevent them from modifying it to use someone else's url or a random unregistered one as the parameter.

Sure you could build a PHP API that they run on their server. The JS API connects to the PHP API and the PHP API is zend-guard encoded (or some other source protection code system) but then there's still going to be people who decode the file to get back to your source and mess with you. Granted there'd be far less people able to do that, and the average user would just rather use your API as it is. Then you also have the issue of people not being able to run your API on servers that don't have the ability to run encoded PHP files.

In the end you have to determine your level of desired security and authentication, but since your API is running in JavaScript in the client browser, there is very little available beyond obfuscation.

I'd say your best option would be to simply have your JS code snag the URL of the current page and send it with the API request. From there your server can process the URL to get the root domain and any other info you want to store.

If you want to prevent people from "spoofing" requests for other user's website urls, you could implement a PHP API that gets installed on the user's server at a certain place. For example http://www.domain.com/my-app-name.php

All JS API calls should go through that script. When the user downloads your API they should enter their website URL and some other info. Your system generates a "key" and injects it into the script before packaging it for them to download. That key is valid for their domain and used to encode all transmission to/from your API using say blowfish or another 2-way encryption algorithm. This way when your API receives a request from their PHP API file, you're getting the url of the page that request was made from, encoded with a key that only you and the admin of that site have. So the request comes through as something like this: metromapper.org/api?site=[url_encoded_page_address]&req=[encrypted_request]

Your server uses the page url to determine what key should be used to decrypt the data. It then decrypts the data. If the data is corrupted or doesn't decrypt into what you expect, then it's an invalid request and you should just exit returning nothing.

The reason I suggest using a PHP file for encryption as opposed to writing the encryption into JS is because you don't want to burden the client (each site visitor) with the load of encryption/decryption and PHP is going to handle it much faster than JS would since there are libraries made to handle those tasks for you.

At any rate that should get you on the right track to being able to keep track of and validate requests for different sites against your API.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and great ideas.

About HTTP_REFERER yes I know it can be spoofed, but I'm more concerned about tracking it in say 90% of the cases than I am about security or spoofing. Same goes with JS.

I won't be able to tell make the user that hits the JSON API call pass the domain.  I could but it's a last resort.  Plus that is a lot easier to change than the REFERER.  But I would consider this as a last resort.

I can't require people to put a PHP file on their server that all the calls go through.  For one, most servers don't use PHP, but also it's just a bit too cumbersome.

Comment: Your last idea is the most likely solution: have them generate an encrypted key.  But the issue is that this key would just be plainly visible (along with the site variable) to anyone who looks at the source.  Then they someone can just cut and paste it.  I think I might just have to go with the REMOTE_HOST IP address and then discover the domain from that on the fly.  This doesn't solve the Google server issue for KML, so I'll have to figure that out separately.

Comment: Yeah the suggestion about the key was assuming you use a PHP file on their server. Since the key would only be stored in plaintext server side instead of being in the JS code visible to all their visitors. Using a key system would be the only way to prevent people from invalidating your collected data by modifying the code. Since it would enable you to be sure the request really did come from their site (and wasn't someone modifying the JS code). You could also code the small API file in JSP/ASP if you have that capability. That would make it more widely supported.

Answer (score 2):

You could generate a hash based on the domain name, and let the users of your API send the domain name and the hash in each request. Now since you're API uses PHP you'll have set the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' somewhere in the header. If you do this in PHP you can play around with that a bit. The script below is a simple example of an implementation that doesn't require php on the caller side (domain that uses you're API).

Caller Side (no php required):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function callA() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "//ajaxdomain.com/call.php?"+
                      "dom=www.callerdomain.com&"+
                      "key=41f8201df6cf1322cc192025cc6c5013",
               true);
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        handleResponse(xhttp.responseText);
      }
    }
    xhttp.send();
  }
</script>
```

Ajax Server Side (PHP):

```
<?php
  if($_GET['key']==md5($_GET['dom']."Salt")) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://".$_GET['dom']);
  }
?>
```

This way the header would also be placed if the call came from a malicious domain, but rest will bounce because of a Cross Origin Exception, and thus no result will be given.

For the sake code space I used a md5 hash in this example, but you could use more complex hashes if you want. Note that you should (as always) keep the used salt secret.

I put a working example online at the following (sub)domains. The pages are identical.

[cors1.serioushare.com](http://cors1.serioushare.com) - Only works on 'CORS 1' button.
[cors2.serioushare.com](http://cors2.serioushare.com) - Only works on 'CORS 2' button.