# CORS Implementation in php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

Simply I'm making an app using Codeigniter as PHP framework and I'm using API for rendering the view on cross site with ajax request. Now my problem is I have hosted all my files in one site say homnath.com.np and provided the API key to different websites by storing their webURL into database, say abc.com, xyz.com and many others. Now when xyz.com hits in my site homnath.com by ajax, how could I know the webURL that is hitting on my site homnath.com by API key, and how to allow for it for CORS if it is a valid and listed website. Moreover I have used 
           header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
to allow for all webURLS and now I want to filter them and provide access to only those which are listed on my database. How can I do it in controller of codeigniter. I want to block for rest of the sites.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946744/getting-the-domain-that-calls-an-php-file-on-your-server-through-ajax

Comment: But the above link didn't solve my whole case. So its not the duplicate

Comment: what do you mean by whole case it will guide you and you can then add the error you are getting after trying it no one will give you ready made answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this you can check for the URL as

```
         $incomingOrigin = $webURL;

         $hotdat = array();
          foreach ($hotelURL as $releted){         //$hotelURL is an array from your database
          $addURL = $releted->url;              // $releted->url the db field name for url
         array_push($hotdat, $addURL);
         }

       if ($incomingOrigin !== null && isOriginAllowed($incomingOrigin, $hotdat)== TRUE)
      {
       header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $incomingOrigin");
     }else{
        echo ("CSRF protection in POST request: detected invalid Origin header: " . $incomingOrigin);
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://bookingpoints.com");
     }
```